# What are some popular Engish songs that have Mandarin translations?

Tags: mandarin, songs

I know a few like:

*Perfect* by Sophie Chen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjKumvgMy7s

*Call Me Maybe* by Dawen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grWp1KzmTYM

Are there any others?

Comment: Among the songs that are generally translated into other languages, Disney songs and music for worship are often the best ports of call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just off the top of my head:-

https://youtu.be/RC29_-aaeC0 (Tennessee Waltz)

https://youtu.be/DVwc-aJ6PSI  (Oh, Carol)

https://youtu.be/uqsOqk58UoM  (Sha Lalala)

https://youtu.be/vlhdL7Woovs  (More than I can say)